# Custom sortable pages on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, drag-drop

I created a custom post type but I want to put a functionality like the Menu Options located on Appearance>Menu.

Which I can just choose a page on the side metabox then add it on the sortable area.

And on the sortable area, I am arrange the order of the pages and save the arrangement when I publish or update the post.

It needs to have different arrangement for each post. Please help. I am stack on this for 3 days now.

Comment: This sounds like advanced functionality that would require a custom plugin

Comment: Yes. But I am really creating my own custom plugin and it has a functionality like this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with Advanced Custom Fields: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

An Options Page isn't free though.